# How to reclaim the /WEB-INF URL in App engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I want all URLs, except the ones that map to a static file, to be handled by my Servlet.

I have set it up correctly, and it works like a charm *except* that the url `/WEB-INF/` gets always handled by the static file handler in App-engine.

Even if I put this in my `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/s/**" />
    <exclude path="/WEB-INF" />
</static-files
```

it still handles the `/WEB-INF` url statically. (The `/s/**` path is my app specific path to static files.)

Moreover, all paths beginning with `/WEB-INF` are also handled statically, although the files are not actually served as expected.

Is there any way to stop the static handler from capturing the `/WEB-INF`path?

Comment: Why do you absolutely want to have URLs starting with /WEB-INF? Why not choose something else?

Comment: I have different projects which require them. One of them acts as a URL shortner and another creates URLs based on user-activity. I would prefer not to add a special-case to the URL choosing logic.

Comment: You're going to have to add special cases, or make sure your URL generator can't generate these as valid URLs. There are other invalid URLs, like anything starting with `/_ah/`, and `/form`.

Comment: Thanks @NickJohnson! If you say so, the case is sealed. The `/_ah/` was guaranteed not to be created by my existing logic. I was not aware of `/form`. Is there a consolidated list somewhere?

Comment: @HRJ From the Python docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Reserved_URLs - there isn't one for the Java runtime, but the list, to the best of my knowledge, is that plus /WEB-INF/.

Answer (score 0):

`/WEB-INF` is not an externally accessible resource. You can not type `/WEB-INF/web.xml` in your browser, can you?

It is used as a server-private directory where configuration data is stored.

Comment: I must clarify, I am familiar with what `WEB-INF` folder is. The problem is that the URL is handled by the static file server rather than passed to my servlet.

Comment: Huh? It is not supposed to be handled by anything. What does it show if you go to `http://youappname.appspot.com/WEB-INF/web.xml` in your browser?

Comment: It gives an "Error : NOT_FOUND" for any URL beginning with `/WEB-INF`

Comment: Of course. This path is not to be accessed externally. Why do you want to map it to a servlet?